# weatherproof in use box/cover for Nema 6-20?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I would like to add 2 infrared heaters to my patio (3000w each) The Bromic eclipse heaters come with 6-20 plugs. It would be nice to have an in-use weatherproof cover so that can stay plugged in full time, Can I just use a standard 2 gang outdoor box and cover or will there be space heat issues? Separately, does it make more sense to do 12awg runs or 1 awg run (approx 30 feet to panel)

Comment: What makes you think that NEMA 6-20s need a different in-use cover from NEMA 5-20s, or NEMA 5-15s for that matter?

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be too much trouble finding an in-use cover for a NEMA 6-20 receptacle.

[image]

*Wait. They come like that?*  Yeah.

On a 240V circuit, I don't even bother "crunching the numbers" on voltage drop til 180 feet distance.  So #12 should be fine.

The maximum capacity (for heaters) of a 20A circuit is 3840 watts. Therefore you will need 2 circuits.

**You cannot run one 30A circuit with #10 wire** because 20A sockets are NOT allowed on 30A circuits, and it violates the heater instructions.  (and also 30A circuits only support 5760W of heater, and you have 6000).

Note that 240V/20A circuits follow the same rules as 120V/20A circuits... the circuit can have as many sockets as you want, and 15A sockets (NEMA 6-15) are allowed on 20A circuits as long as the circuit has more than 1 socket.  Receptacles don't need to be dedicated to an appliance (unless the appliance instructions require this: NEC 110.3).

Is this patio anywhere near where someone might want to plug in an ... *electric vehicle*?  Because 3840 watts will give a pretty respectable charge rate... nearly 3 times the piddly 1440W level 1 charging, and near the max for smaller EVs like the Nissan Leaf 1st Gen.  A guest might appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your information that the heaters are 240V, 3000 Watts / 12.5 Amps each, you should be looking at running two circuits of #12 AWG.   You can terminate into a two gang box and use a in-use cover similar to this. If the heaters will be far apart, you might want to run a single outlet and cover to two different locations. You'll want double pole breakers or handle ties on single breakers

[image]